# Wrong symbols in file where result of execution placed

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, file-writing

I'm new in linux and I encountered a problem, I tried to put the result of "neofetch" execution in to file by using:

```
[user@user-pc ~]$ neofetch > sytem_info
```

then I used nano and the result was:

```
^[[?25l^[[?7l^[[0m^[[32m^[[1m██████████████████  ████████
██████████████████  ████████
██████████████████  ████████
██████████████████  ████████
████████            ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
████████  ████████  ████████
^[[14A^[[9999999D^[[31C^[[0m^[[1m^[[32m^[[1muser^[[0m@^[[32m^[[1user- 
pc^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m---------------^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mOS^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m Manjaro Linux x86_64^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mKernel^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m 4.14.31-1-MANJARO^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mUptime^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m 2 hours, 18 mins^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mPackages^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m 970^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mShell^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m bash 4.4.19^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mDE^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m GNOME^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mTheme^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m Adapta-Nokto-Maia [GTK2/3]^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mIcons^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m Moka [GTK2/3]^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mTerminal^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m gnome-terminal^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mCPU^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m Pentium E5200 (2) @ 2.500GHz^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mGPU^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m Intel G33^[[0m
^[[31C^[[0m^[[32m^[[1mMemory^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m 1657MiB / 1986MiB^[[0m

^[[31C^[[0m^[[30m^[[40m   ^[[0m^[[31m^[[41m   ^[[0m^[[32m^[[42m   ^[[0m^[[33m^[[43m   ^[[0m^[[34m^[[44m   ^[[0m^$


^[[?25h^[[?7h
```

Text editor in GUI shows the same thing.
In terminal this program working well, also I tried to put results of another programs into file and there weren't any problems, so I wonder what is the problem with "neofetch",is it wrong encoding or something else?

Comment: for the record, those are valid control chars that force the shell to output formatted text: bold, color, underline, etc; e.g. from the shell, one could run: `printf '^[[0m^[[31m^[[1mShell^[[0m^[[0m:^[[0m bash 4.4.19^[[0m'` to print out `Shell: bash 4.4.19` (with `Shell` in red); the `^[` aren't copy/pastable, though: they are a `Ctrl+[[` followed by some code (31C, 32m), the string, then a closing `Ctrl+[[` command...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) is a command-line tool that generates very graphical, colorful output. The color, bold, underline, etc can be disabled (via config file, command line options, or [customizing the printing](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Customizing-Info)), but I'm not sure if there's a single command to disable it all. You can get rid of the logo via `neofetch --off`, but it will still include all the formatting chars you see when looking at the output file in an editor. Rather than opening the output file an editor, if you just display the file ( `cat system_info` ), it'll display the file, just as if you ran it without redirecting the output.